# Python 3 Matplotlib: Plotting Line Tangent to Bubbles in Bubble Chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bubble-chart

So I am using a Matplotlib bubble chart and am trying to align all of my bubbles to a tangent line. I would like this line to be tangent to the bottoms of all bubbles. More specifically, I am trying to align them to the horizontal line y = 0 (the y-axis). How should I go about this?

Attached below is an image of my current chart, without alignment.

I would need to adjust my y-axis for each bubble based on its scalar, but this scalar is not a given radius or diameter; instead, it is scaled so that the bubbles are not huge or tiny relative to each other, according to the Matplotlib documentation. However, I cannot find how it is translated over, so I do not know if I can adjust the y-axis positions based on these. Is there something that I am missing? Is there perhaps a better method?

Thank you!

[image]